# How to call <li> id values from the property file using java?

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently I'm working on **Selenium WebDriver** and **Java**. I have a master script which runs all the other scripts. The master script as follows:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
public class MasterScript {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
//*****************************************************
//   Calling Methods
//*****************************************************
LoginOneReports utilObj = new LoginOneReports ();// calling my 1st LoginOneReports.java
WebDriver driver;
driver=utilObj.setUp();
if(utilObj.Login()){
System.out.println("Login sucessfully completed");
} else {
System.out.println("Login failed");
System.exit(0);
}
NewPR utilObj1 = new NewPR(driver);// calling my 2st NewPR.java Here I need to change
if(utilObj1.test()){
System.out.println("NewPR KPI page has opened");
} else {
System.out.println("NewPR KPI not able to open");
}
FilterSection utilObj2 =new FilterSection(driver);//calling my 3st Filtersection.java
utilObj2.FilterMatching();
}
}
```

1. I have a list of kPI's as follows:

[image]
Currently in my NewPR.java script I'm directly going and clicking on the `NewPR`
The script as follows:

```
Log.info("Clicking on Overview and Evolution PR link");
if(existsElement("ext-new-prs")==true){
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.id("ext-new-prs") ));
Thread.sleep(6000);
}
else{
Log.info("element not present");
System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");
}
return driver.getCurrentUrl().equals("https://10.4.16.159/extranet_newprs/reports/type/default/");
}
```

Instead of going and clicking each time one KPI. I need to store in a property file where all the list of values in screenshot. Then i need to call any 1 or more KPI and i need to run the 3rd script that is `FilterSection.java`

My problem is all the KPI HTML are looks like this

```
<li>
<a id="ext-pr" class="submenu ext-pr" name="ext-pr" href="https://10.4.16.159/reports/">Problem Reports (PR)</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a id="ext-pr-backlog-age" class=" ext-pr-backlog-age" name="ext-pr-backlog-age" href="https://10.4.16.159/extranet_prbacklogage/reports/type/default/">Age</a>
</li>
<li>
<a id="ext-timetoassign-prs" class=" ext-timetoassign-prs" name="ext-timetoassign-prs" href="https://10.4.16.159/extranet_timetoassignprs/reports/type/default/">Average Time To Assign</a>
</li>
```

I don't have idea how to store these set of values in a property file. could anyone suggest me solution..

Comment: Could anyone please help me for this

Comment: I don't know about your properties file but why don't you just use Selenium API to find your `<a>`links and click on it ? Something like : `List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector('li a'));` and a `for` loop to click on each element of the `elems` list

Comment: I don't how to store the <li> id="ext-timetoassign-prs" in the property file also. then only i need to call that value from property file and i need to click in the FE

Comment: Log.info("Clicking on Avg Time to Deliver PR link");if(existsElement("ext-timetodeliver-prs")==true){WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("ext-timetodeliver-prs"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();Thread.sleep(6000);}else{ Log.info("element not present");System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");}

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not very clear to me what you are trying to do. You need to store all the `id` values in a properties file ?

Comment: The above code i can directly click on one KPI in the FE. But it need to stored in property file that i don't know

Comment: Yes all id values i need to store in the property file. Then i need to call any one id value and need to click in the FE.

Comment: please refer the KPI list in the above image

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to load a properties file :

```
public static Properties loadPropertiesFile(){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {

        input = new FileInputStream("path_to_your_properties_file");

        // load a properties file
        properties.load(input);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you only provide a file name in `path_to_your_properties_file`, the file will be located in your project directory. But you can provide a path to a file also I think.

For convenience, use a property file composed of something like that :

```
total_ids=5
id_1=ext-pr
id_2=ext-pr-backlog-age
id_3=ext-timetoassign-prs
id_4=other_id
id_5=other_id_again
```

Then after loading your file with the first given method, you can loop through the ids with :

```
int total = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("total_ids"));
for(int i=1 ; i<= total ; i++){
    String identifier = properties.getProperty("id_"+i);
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(identifier));
    // Do your tests en 'element'
}
```

Is it what you want to do ?

Comment: String total = properties.getProperty("total_ids");
 int total_ids;
 for(int i=1 ; i<= total_ids ; i++){// showing error for i<=total_ids
     String identifier = properties.getProperty("id_"+i);

Comment: my mistake, it's `i<=total`

Comment: int total = properties.getProperty("total_ids");//Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int.. If i change as String then for(int i=1 ; i<= total ; i++){ The operator <= is undefined for the argument type(s) int, String

Comment: I have not tested my code, you are right, just add Integer.parseInt as on my edit

Comment: int totaInteger.parseInt(properties.getProperty("total_ids")); it is showing null java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Comment: Well, I'm sorry but I think I've given you enough pointers to solve your problem. You should be good to solve by yourself now. I can't code your whole program here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56933/discussion-between-user11111-and-singe31).